PostgreSQL output from multiple schemas
Query below pulls enrollments for one client (compid 12461)
Trying to pull enrollment for all clients in our system, since it is in the “company schema”, would I have to loop? (compid ranges from 12461-16384)
select distinct emp.fname
              , emp.lname
              , emp.emergname
              , med.compid
              , med.pyrid
              , med.empno
              , med.partstart
              , med.partend
              , med.partann
              , med.entrydate
              , med.deldate
              , med.deltime 
from compid12461.medpart med 
join compid12461.empinfo emp 
  on emp.empno = med.empno 
where med.partend > current_date 
order by emp.lname

Tried to loop but getting syntax errors.

order is missing, you only have by. That should be order by

@FrankHeikens, it there current_dateorder by it just needs a space added current_date order by.

Yes you will need to loop through the schemas as you cannot do ... from *.medpart med join *.empinfo ....

The syntax errors you're getting are probably because plain SQL doesn't offer loops like that. You need a PL/pgSQL table/SRF function, where you loop using for v_schema in select distinct nspname from pg_namespace where nspname ilike 'compid%' loop return query execute format('select...from %1$I.medpart med join %1$I.empinfo...',v_schema); end loop;. That's one of the problems in schema-based multi-tenancy. You could consider setting up a common schema with views that union all common objects from individual tenants' schemas. If you used partitioning+RLS instead, it'd be a non-issue.

The syntax errors you're getting are probably because plain SQL doesn't offer loops like that. You could use a PL/pgSQL table function to loop over schemas from pg_namespace:
demo at db<>fiddle
create function f()returns table(
    fname     text,        lname     text
  , emergname text,        compid    bigint
  , pyrid     bigint,      empno     bigint
  , partstart timestamptz, partend   timestamptz
  , partann   text,        entrydate date
  , deldate   date,        deltime   timetz) as $f$
declare v_schema text;
begin 
for v_schema in select nspname 
                from pg_namespace 
                where nspname ilike 'compid%' 
loop return query execute format($dsql$
        select distinct emp.fname
                      , emp.lname
                      , emp.emergname
                      , med.compid
                      , med.pyrid
                      , med.empno
                      , med.partstart
                      , med.partend
                      , med.partann
                      , med.entrydate
                      , med.deldate
                      , med.deltime 
        from %1$I.medpart as med
        join %1$I.empinfo as emp 
          on emp.empno = med.empno 
        where med.partend > current_date 
        order by emp.lname 
   $dsql$, v_schema); 
end loop; 
end $f$ language plpgsql;

select distinct * from f();

That's one of the problems in schema-based multi-tenancy. You could consider setting up a common schema with views that union all common objects from individual tenants' schemas:
create schema common;
create view common.medpart as 
select 'compid12461' as tenant,*from compid12461.medpart union all
select 'compid12462' as tenant,*from compid12461.medpart union all
select 'compid12463' as tenant,*from compid12461.medpart;

If you used partitioning+RLS (pool model, tenant discriminator) instead, it'd be a non-issue.
